# iCloud storage insufficient

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

[image: Insufficient Storage]

As you can see whenever I try to backup my iPhone it tells me there is insufficient storage. All I want to do is backup my contacts and all super basic data in case something happens to my phone. I have backed it up a couple of times to my computer but I would like the more consistent back ups from iCloud.

[image: Plenty of space available]

I have next to nothing stored in my iCloud like I honestly do not know what it is and so I cannot understand why it will not let me backup my phone. Then when I try to backup my phone even though I have every app turned off it says my backup will be over 5 gb. How do I make it so my backup is under the 5 gb limit???? I have looked at all the other forums and have not found anything helpful. It tells me my iPhone has never been backed up before.

[image: over 5 gb]

On a side note can you tell me why Netflix wants to use 150 mb of my iCloud?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I knew it was going to be simple but for some reason apple decides that text messages should be backed up without ever explicitly saying so, so old text messages take up gigabytes of iCloud space.

Comment: that seems pretty extreme. Text files are usually pretty small

Comment: @jmh not if there’s a lot of media embedded...

Comment: @jmh you'd be surprised...

Comment: so there's basically no way to have a reasonably-sized backup? with messages it's either back them up directly to the cloud, or as part of a backup image that goes to the cloud? no way to say, "None of the above" if you don't care about backing them up?